Making map using react-zoom-pan-pinch
I'm trying to make a map out of an image and a html map component. I will wrap everything in-side a pre-build react component for zoom, but it is here the problems start. As you can see, I use htmls build-in map function, where I define a cirlce-area. When I use just this, the link works fine. When I wrap the zoom around it, it doesn't work, do anyone know why?
"use client"
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react'
import {
    TransformWrapper,
    TransformComponent,
    useControls,
} from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";

import MapV4 from './MapV4';
import CampingBilde from '../images/camping.png'

// Test-component as map
const Map = ({mapRef, mapDimensions}) => {
    return (<>
        <img 
            src={CampingBilde.src} 
            ref={mapRef} 
            useMap="#image-map" 
            className='w-full h-full' 
            style={{ height: mapDimensions.height, width: mapDimensions.width }} 
        />
        <map name="image-map">
            <area target="_self" alt="16" id="area" title="16" href="https://www.google.com" coords="150,150,75" shape="circle" className='hover:cursor-pointer' />
        </map>
    </>)
}


function MapForClient() {
    // Defining ref and size of map
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
    const mapRef = useRef();
    const [mapDimensions, setMapDimensions] = useState({height: null, width: null});

    const zoomByBreakpoint = (width) => {
        return width > 448 ? 1 : 3;
    };

    // set width and height on img
    const handleResize = () => {
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        setZoom(zoomByBreakpoint(width));

        if (mapRef.current) {
            setMapDimensions({
                height: mapRef.current.offsetHeight,
                width: mapRef.current.offsetWidth
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        setZoom(zoomByBreakpoint(width));

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        handleResize(); // Set dimensions on initial render

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }, []);

    // Log zoom
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Zoom:", zoom);
    }, [zoom]);

    // Log dimensions
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Height:", mapDimensions.height, "Width:", mapDimensions.width);
    }, [mapDimensions]);

    return (
        <section className='w-full md:w-2/3 h-full bg-[#c7df8e]'>
            <TransformWrapper
                initialScale={1}
                initialPositionX={0}
                initialPositionY={0}
            >
                <TransformComponent>
                    <Map mapRef={mapRef} mapDimensions={mapDimensions} />
                </TransformComponent>
            </TransformWrapper>
            <Map mapRef={mapRef} mapDimensions={mapDimensions} />
        </section>
    );
}

export default MapForClient;

As mentioned, I tried to have the component outside the zoom, then it works fine, but I need zoom.
